# Mobile: Hiding other options

Tags: forms, mobile, buttons, registration, choices

The registration page would only ask for simple things: name, e-mail address, password, and phone number, and "user type". For the user type, say the choices are:

- Buyer
- Seller
- Middleman
- Visitor

By choosing a "role", they'd have access to different functions of the app and they can choose to change their role after registration. It's just a matter tailor-fitting the app based on the type of user.

As much as possible, I wouldn't like to go for the dropdown menu (unless a lot of you *really* recommend it...). The app would mainly be for Buyers and Sellers and not really intended for Middlemen and Visitors, but they are still allowed to have an account and use the app, no biggie.

I was thinking on having a horizontal row of buttons, and the default selected button would be **Buyer**. And because mobile phones have a lesser, limited width, the other options would be hidden like so...

```
      I am a...
[Buyer] [Seller] [...]
```

I'm still not sure how the `[...]` would show the other selectable roles.

My questions:

1. Should it be in the first or last part of the registration?
2. Would icons (on top of Buyer, Seller, etc.) be overkill?
3. Is the `[...]` button obvious enough for the non-intended users?
4. **Should I hide the other options, or show them but make the font and button smaller?**

Possible 2x2 layout:

```
         I'm a...

[           ] [          ]
[   Buyer   ] [  Seller  ]
[           ] [          ]

[ middleman ] [  visitor ]
```

The web app currently has a drop-down option for this. With your suggestion for the mobile, would you recommend the same approach for the web app?

**P.S.** I'm only interested in knowing how to place and implement the options for the user role. No need to worry about the functionality of the app :)

Comment: I'm Assuming that this is an marketplace model e-commerce app? could you add some context to your question?

Comment: Will users **always** be only one of these categories?  What if a seller wants to buy something?  What if someone registers as a visitor and later decides to become a buyer?

Comment: @dan1111, there won't be a problem in one type of user doing another task, it's already implemented. I'm really more interested in the choice option

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the 2x2 option. It displays the preferred options at the top, big and bold. If you're not one of those you look further and find the other 2 options.

The [...] thing doesn't help you. If something is not displayed directly people generally don't find it. For example: items in dropdown navigations are clicked far less than normal (visible navigation) items.

You could also ditch the Middleman and Visitor options as they are not your core users for the app. Think about the functionality, would that be different if these people were to select either the Buyer or Seller options?